# What is the word for what an applicant applies to?

Tags: word-choice

If you are applying to a school you are an "applicant". What is the word for the thing you're applying to?

Similar to the sentence "*the stalker stalks the stalkee",* what would be in the blank in the sentence *The applicant applies to the ______*?

Comment: You can apply to a lot of different things. So there is no single word for all the things that can be applied to. It doesn't follow the same logic with stalker/stalkee.

Comment: There's really only one sense of "apply" as an intransitive verb that makes sense here ("to make or submit a request, as for information or access"). It's really pretty clear from context.

Comment: If you're going to use neologisms like *stalkee* why not just make up a neoloism here too?

Comment: You apply to the school, or to the company, or to the committee, or whatever.

Comment: How about *applicand?* That would be a typically anglicized Latin passive participle, where *applicant* would be the similarly anglicized active participle. The relation between the two parallels that between agent *-er* and patient *-ee.*

Answer (score 1):

There are, as noted above, many things to which one can apply. A general concept that covers not every but a lot of things to which one can apply is an **offer** (of a position, grant, conference participation).

Answer (score 0):

[*Grantor*](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/grantor) might be the closest.

> An individual who conveys or transfers ownership of property. Syn: assignor, bequeather, bestower, contributor, devisor, donator, giver, investor, rewarder, testator. (TFD)

Answer (score 0):

Position. "I am writing to apply for the position of Assistant Professor at  . . ."

Comment: would anybody like to explain why this isn't correct? Downvote without a comment isn't helpful.

Comment: I agree that a downvote without a comment isn't helpful. I think that the downvoter saw your answer as inappropriate for the question asked. The OP wanted a word that would cover the institution or person  your applicant was applying to.

Comment: @tunny - Maybe the right answer is "institution or person".